# Android- Change the Sample size or bits per sample for audio playback

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Is there a way to change the Audio's `sample size` or `bits per sample` (bit rate i guess??) for audio playback.
Like if the audio has 24-bits per sample, I want to change it to 16-bits per sample
before playback. Because 24bits and 32bits are not yet supported in Android.
I'm using `MediaPlayer` class.

Is there something like:

```
 MediaPlayer media = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio);
 media.set______;
 media.start();
```

Or any ways to change the bits per sample in the device side. Although I can change the bits per sample in my server side using SOX, I just wanted to know if it is possible to change the bits per sample in Android.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't get it. Why MediaRecorder?

Comment: sry for my mistake just create instance of MediaPlayer class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot control the sample size or bitrate with [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html). If you want to do this you will need to decode the audio yourself using a library like [FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org) and then use [AudioTrack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html) for playback.

Comment: Is any way to use 24bit samples directly, without converting them to ENCODING_PCM_FLOAT?